# Lravel 5.2 session::forget() and session::flush() not working

Tags: laravel-5

i have just make a sub authentication Middleware in my Laravel 5.2 application which use Laravel session to store data.

I can put my data to Laravel session
But when i want to delete that variable form session it working for only that request when page redirect or someone reload  the page that variable still exists.

*In My controller File*

```
 class SubmissionController extends Controller
{
public function login(Request $request){
    if($request->session()->has('submission')) return redirect('/submission-directory');

    return view('submission.login');
}

public function dologin(Request $request){
    if(!$request->get('password') == "reader") return redirect('/submission-directory/login')->withErrors('errors.wrong-password');

    Session::put('submission','yes');

    $redirect = $request->session()->pull('submission_redirect','/submission-directory');
    return redirect($redirect);
}

public function index(Request $request){

    dump($request->session()->all());

    $request->session()->forget('submission');

    dump($request->session()->all());

    die('coming here');
}
}
```

[image]

but when I reload the page You can session is still exists..

[image]

Notice :: I have put all the routs in  web Middleware group

*Route.php*

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
     Route::group(['prefix'=>'/submission-directory'],function(){
      Route::get('/login','submissionController@login');

      Route::post('/login',['as'=>'submission.login','uses'=>'SubmissionController@doLogin']);

      Route::group(['middleware'=>'submission'],function(){
       Route::get('/','SubmissionController@index');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

IN Controller :

```
use Session;

public function index(Request $request)
{
dump(Session::all());
Session::forget('submission');
print_r((Session::all());
die;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your approach but i have already tried this and found that it is not working too.